# Solving a PDE with variable separation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can I solve the PDE $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+xu=0$$ using the separation of variables method?

Applying this I found that $$X''Y+XY''+xXY=0$$  But I can't see what do since this part.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: \begin{align} X''Y + XY'' + xXY &= 0 \\ \implies \frac{X''}{X} + \frac{Y''}{Y} + x &= 0 \\ \implies \frac{X''}{X} + x &= - \frac{Y''}{Y} \\ &= \lambda \end{align}